# How to remove states in ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I used angularJS 1.5.8 and ui-router 0.3.1 , and in my app I used stateProvider to dynamically create lots of states and I think it's better to delete them to avoid too much memory usage.
I searched a lot, but didn't find the solution. However, it seems that stateRegistry could do this. [a link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/88c6494471ce2093cbe6543574df91ecf8f46dc9)! [a link](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/classes/state.stateregistry.html)! 
I tried to read the source code but sadly can't understand. Wish someone could give me instructions. Thanks.